# Append Date Stamp to 'onClick' event in Android Studio

Tags: android, date, variables, onclick, savechanges

I am writing code which increments an integer variable by 1 every time that textview is clicked. I want to record click events with dates so that I can produce a graph based on monthly history or weekly history.

How can I append date stamp to an onclick event?

for example, when the user will click on 'depressed' textview, I would like it to be saved with timestamp so that I can use it to tell the user that he was depressed for 7 days in past month and also show it with a chart.

I want to work with dates along with variables, there will be no user input in my app. Like FITBIT, which presents you your history of health performance on daily, weekly, monthly basis.

Here is my code which save variables in SharedPrefs and also increments them

```
//Retrieve the stored data for Values.
        SHAREDPREFS = getSharedPreferences(VALUES,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SHAREDPREFS.edit();

        switch (view.getId())
        {
        //increment values in VALUES sharedprefs to keep history
            case R.id.textView_depressed:
                int i_depressed= SHAREDPREFS.getInt("save_depressed",0);
                if (i_depressed>0)
                {
                    i_depressed++;
                    editor.putInt("save_depressed",i_depressed);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                else
                {
                    i_depressed++;
                    editor.putInt("save_depressed",i_depressed);
                    editor.apply();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Depressed = " + i_depressed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

this is what I have written so far, as a draft. i_depressed is a variable and whenver user will click on depressed textview, it will save the incremented value. I want it to save incremented value with a date and then I want to retrieve value of this variable in a date-range like last week, last 15 days, last month or specific month.

Comment: You can use `new Date()` whenever you want to get the current date of the system. This way you can store it. Anyway, I would think another way of storing that info better than SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just saving a single variable, you can store a JSON array with every entry of the array contains a touple of (incremented value, timestamp).

Whenever you launch the app you can load the array into the memory.Since all the timestamps would be in strictly increasing order you can find the value in the desired range.

Comment: How do I do that can you provide any links to documentation? I am a beginner at this